# Conviertiendo un archivo .htaccess de Apache a un archivo de configuración Nginx

Tags: nginx

Después de mucho tiempo queriendo cambiarme de Apache (hospedaje compartido) a Nginx (mi VPS), lo he podido hacer hoy pero el único obstáculo que se me ha enfrentado es a la hora del archivo de configuración Nginx.

Mi archivo de configuración de .htaccess es:

```
# site.com .htaccess
RewriteBase /

# Error 400
ErrorDocument 400 site.com?error=1

# Error 401
ErrorDocument 401 site.com?error=2

# Error 403
ErrorDocument 403 site.com?error=3

# Error 404
ErrorDocument 404 site.com?error=4

# Error 500
ErrorDocument 500 site.com?error=5

# Redirect www
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.com/$1 [R=301]

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http 
RewriteRule ^ site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove PHP file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# Remove TXT file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.txt -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.txt [L]

# Rewrite for shortened URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?url=$1.php
```

Mi archivo de configuración Nginx actualmente es:

```
server { 

    listen 80; 
    server_name website.mc-pe.us; 

    root /home/web/site.com/;
    index index.php; 

    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
    } 
}
```

Me gustaría que mi archivo de configuración Nginx tenga todas las reglas que mi antiguo .htaccess.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes considerar [winginx](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) tiene como herramienta un `translate`de  las reglas configuradas por el `.htaccess` a una configuración `nginx`, no está de mas comprobar con la documentación de [configuracion nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)  `nginx` si el translate es correcto.

Comment: No funciona para mí, me da un error 404 cuando accedo a / (misitio.com) y tengo que ingresar /index.php para cargar el archivo index y cuando intento acceder /create.php ya que se convierte en /create no funciona y da un error 404.  puedes darme el codigo ? Por si acaso llevo 4 horas seguidas buscando unas soluciones e intentado literalmente más de 30 codigos. Gracias